# Mutate field from other dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

```
MAGINA<-mutate(MAGINA, 
      T_MED = mean(filter(Clima,between(Clima$Fecha, MAGINA$Fecha,MAGINA$Fecha+days(6)))[["Temp. media"]]))
```

I would like to get another field with the mean of sevendays of temperature from the other dataframe, but i have the follow error.

> Evaluation error: Evaluation error: Expecting a single value:
>   [extent=4483]...

Comment: Avoid using `$` within mutate, avoid nesting fucntions, instead use pipes: `mydata %>% filter(...) %>% mutate(...)` instead of `mutate(mean(filter(`

Comment: ... and welcome to SO. Please (!) have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask